# How to install icon in a ubuntu package

Tags: ubuntu, icons, package

I am trying to create a application installation package for my app on ubuntu 14, as far as I know the package is in debian package format, correct me if I am wrong

My question is **how to install the icon file** for my app, from what I am learned that icon is defined in a desktop file and will be copied to /usr/share/applications dir, how can I copy the icon file to the destination from the package?

Answer (score 1):

application launchers are actually files stored in your computer, with a ‘`.desktop`’ extension. So besides changing the icon theme, you can edit the ‘`.desktop`’ to change the launcher icon for an specific application.

#### 1. Edit the ‘firefox.desktop’

The ‘.desktop’ files are usually stored in “`/usr/share/applications/`”. For some applications that are installed in user’s directory, you may find the .desktop files in "`~/.local/share/applications/`" directory.

To edit the firefox.desktop, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on keyboard to open terminal. When it opens, run:

`cd /usr/share/applications`

`sudo gedit firefox.desktop`

It will navigate to `/usr/share/applications/` directory and open the firefox.desktop file via gedit editor. You can run `ls |more` to list all available files in that directory

#### 2. Change the value of Icon

In gedit window, scroll down to find out the line that starts with “`Icon=`” and change its value to the exact path to your NEW icon file. The image is usually .png file in 64×64 or 128×128.
[image: edit desktop file]

#### 3. After saved the changes, open the unity dash and search the launcher and see the result:

[image: icon]

Comment: Thanks Raju, what I want to do is to install my app's icon(which I already have) to the system, I am not intend to replace the icon for other applications, and I don't want to create a theme either

Comment: Hi Raju, thanks very much for your input, but still it's not what I want, I do know how to do this manully, what I want is how to achieve this when install my app, I guess it something to do with how to package the app.but anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this guide (https://web.archive.org/web/20190328173907/http://www.king-foo.com/2011/11/creating-debianubuntu-deb-packages/) for more info.

TL;DR is at the bottom but i recommend you read the whole thing.

I am going to assume you already know how to set up a deb. If you don't then read the guide posted.

The general idea is that whatever files you put in various folders in your deb, then they will be copied to that destination on the computer. For example if you put `helloworld.sh` in `YourApplication/usr/bin` then `helloworld.sh` will be copied to `/usr/bin` on the computer.

Following this premise, go into your folder and create /usr/share/applications inside the folder. You can use a file manager or just `mkdir -p YourApplication/usr/share/applications`. Make sure you are outside of the folder or it won't work.

Now copy your icon into that folder.

You're done!

TL;DR:

run `mkdir -p YourApplication/usr/share/applications` and put your icon inside.